# KDE Wayland session crashing when waking from standby or the screenlocker - how to find out why?

Tags: debian, kde, wayland, session

I'm running Debian 11 with KDE and Wayland. This is a problem of Wayland instead of X11 with the version of KDE of Debian11.

When I wake from standby I usually have that other login screen that also shows when booting instead of the one that shows when waking from standby. It starts a new session (and I have to restart all the running apps) instead of resuming the session like it used to when resuming from standby. How to find out what's causing this? If possible any hints that could help solve the problem would be useful.

I know Wayland support on KDE Plasma 5.20.5 isn't good but overall it worked for a long time despite a few issues until a few days ago when it crashes all the time with `The Wayland connection broke. Did the Wayland compositor die?`.

With `sudo journalctl | tail -n 1000` I found these log-entries (after the time the wakeup occurred) that may be relevant:

```
...
systemd-sleep[190007]: System resumed.
polkitd(authority=local)[594]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:21 (system bus name :1.335, object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale .._...UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
...
systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
anacron[190080]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
fwupd[189875]: FuPluginLinuxSwap    could not parse /proc/swaps: Error when getting information for file "/home/username/swapfile": No such file or directory
systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Succeeded
systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
kernel: kwin_wayland[181388]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000000000 sp 00007ffd113c1538 error 14 in kwin_wayland[556620415000+12000]
kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xffffffffffffffd6.
...
org.kde.ActivityManager[189945]: kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
org.kde.ActivityManager[189945]: The Wayland connection broke. Did the Wayland compositor die?
org.kde.ActivityManager[189945]: KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
org.kde.ActivityManager[189945]: KCrash: Application Name = drkonqi path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec pid = 189945
org.kde.ActivityManager[189945]: KCrash: Arguments: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi --appname kactivitymanagerd --apppath /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec --signal 11 --pid 181538 --startupid 0
...
```

`KSystemLog` does not run under Wayland, otherwise it would be easy to quickly check other logs if there are more relevant messages. Is there something else to check?

---

This also happens when being afk and some time after the screenlocker turned on or was turned on. It doesn't happen always but most of the time the machine is left alone. In the logs there's this for example (for one of the crashes):

```
kernel: show_signal_msg: 53 callbacks suppressed
kernel: kwin_wayland[2291]: segfault at 29e700000000 ip 00007ff25989dc70 sp 00007ffe1e2adfe8 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7ff25989d000+7000]
kernel: Code: 00 16 00 00 00 31 c0 48 83 c4 08 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 48 8b 07 ff a0 48 01 00 00 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 <48> 8b 07 ff a0 30 01 00 00 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 8b 07 ff a0 38
org.kde.ActivityManager[2460]: The Wayland connection broke. Did the Wayland compositor die?
org.kde.ActivityManager[2460]: KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
org.kde.ActivityManager[2460]: KCrash: Application Name = kactivitymanagerd path = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec pid = 2460
org.kde.ActivityManager[2460]: KCrash: Arguments: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd
org.kde.ActivityManager[2460]: KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi
pulseaudio[2271]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

---

It started happening when I enabled an additional display under Display Configuration and then only enabled the other display and disabled the former display and then reversed it to switch back to the former display. There have been some crashes in between. [I did this multiple times before as a workaround to be able to switch to another display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/722870) without a crash and without having to end the session as this often works without a crash (only some Qt apps are crashing).

However, doing this never caused this problem until a few days ago. Other than that I only installed a few recent upgrades, the only ones that could be relevant are sudo and firefox. The system has the latest updates. `/home/username/swapfile` does exist. Sadly [it's STILL vulnerable to this bluetooth vulnerability](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/4259) so this may be relevant to fwupd. I also quit the logrotate process once recently because it filled my home drive disk space.